# Can client and server implement different FIX engines?

Tags: fix-protocol

I recently started investigating about the FIX protocol and its implementations, couldn't find too much information related to my question.

I need to create a FIX client for a new trading application we are developing at my job, we are mostly focusing on performance. I'm not sure which engine is running on the server we need to connect to, but I wanted to be sure if I have the freedom to pick my own or not. If yes, are there any performance related issues by connecting two different engines?

Comment: FIX is a protocol. So as long as both sides are following the protocol it does not matter if they are employing different engines or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a FIX server can be implemented with one FIX product, and a FIX client that connects to it can be implemented with a different FIX product. One FIX product might be faster than another, but I am not aware of any reason why you would suffer interoperability or performance problems just because your client is using one FIX implementation and the server is using a different FIX implementation.